# Comparing a string using a stack

Tags: c++, stack

> Let L be the language defined as follows:
>
> 1. The words are made up of strings of a’s followed by b’s.
> 2. The number of a’s is always equal to the number of b’s.
> 3. Examples of words that belong to L are: ab, aabb, aaabbb etc...
>
> One way to test if a word w belong to this language is to use a stack to check if the number of a’s balances the number of b’s.

This is what I though of doing:

1. Check if the length string is even
2. If it is send input to the function
3. Divide length by two and push the a's onto a stack
4. Reverse the string
5. Divide length by two and push the b's onto a stack
6. While the stack isn't empty pop each and store the count of each
7. Compare the count and if they are equal then return 0 or if not return 1

Please see below for the program I implemented:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;

bool isInLanguageL (string w);

int main()

{
    string input;

    cout << "Input any string; ";
    getline(cin,input);

    if (input.length() % 2 != 0)
        cout <<"Pattern entered does not match the language ";
    else
        isInLanguageL(input);

    return 0;
}

bool isInLanguageL (string w)
{
    stack<string> word1, word2;
    string a, b;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < w.length()/2; i++)
    {
           a = w.at(i);
           word1.push(a);

    }

    reverse(w.begin(), w.end());

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < w.length()/2; i++)
    {
           b = w.at(i);
           word2.push(b);

    }


while(!word1.empty() && !word2.empty())
{


    word1.pop();
    count1 = count1++;
    word2.pop();
    count2 = count2++;

}

if(count1 == count2)
    return true;
else
    return false;

}
```

The issue I have with this is despite it working correctly I would appreciate and opinion on it as I feel they may have been another way to approach handling the strings although after racking my brains this was the best solution I could come up with.

What seems a bit silly to me is where I am comparing counts of the two stacks as it's pretty obvious based on the fact that I am not allowing odd numbers to pass into the function that the counts will always be equal which would also be due to the division by 2 in each iteration which clearly rules out the counts ever not being equal.

Also, it's all good and well that I am using the stacks to compare counts but I'm not really doing a check here on whether or not the string matches a pattern. In my mind I would have used the approach of checking a pattern but as the question just wants to see whether a's and b's balance I thought this approach wouldn't be bad.

Any advice on how else to approach this question would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check at CodeReview if you don't have errors. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: quick hint. Easily use one stack, if 'a' push, if 'b' pop. 
When finished, check stack.empty(), if stack is empty. Hurah they were equal ! ONLY if strings start with 'a', else: manage to do the opposite

Comment: Glad to hear there are no errors. I was also grateful that nobody got hurt in the Mayweather vs Pacquiao fight.

Comment: @FirstStep Thanks. Makes sense...

Comment: @FirstStep - doesn't implement the specified language match.  'ababab' would match and according to OP it should not.

Comment: @CrazyEddie you are right.. I just noticed: "They are always equal".. ehm

Comment: @metamorphosis sorry

Comment: @FirstStep No problem. I understand what Crazy Eddie means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO isn't really a site for 'advice' or 'opinion'.  That said, you don't need the massive overhead of a stack to do this.

```
bool match(std::string const& str)
{
    if (str.size() % 2) return false;

    int i = 0;

    auto beg = std::begin(str);
    for (; beg != std::end(str); ++beg)
    {
        if (*beg != 'a') break;
        ++i;
    }

    int j = 0;
    for (; beg != std::end(str); ++beg)
    {
        if (*beg != 'b') break;
        ++j;
    }

    return i == j;
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there ;) +1 for giving him the FISH

Comment: @Crazy Eddie Thanks I'll take these to Code Review going forward. I wasn't aware of this site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this, in a line:

```
bool is_correct = (input.length() % 2 == 0) && std::all_of(input.cbegin(), input.cbegin() + input.length()/2,[](const char letter){return letter=='a';}) &&
      std::all_of(input.cbegin() + input.length()/2, input.cend(),[](const char letter){return letter=='b';});
```

so that the complete program could be that small:

```
int main() {
  std::string input;
  std::cout << "Input any string; ";
  std::getline(std::cin,input);
  bool is_correct = (input.length() % 2 == 0) && std::all_of(input.cbegin(), input.cbegin() + input.length()/2,[](const char letter){return letter=='a';}) &&
      std::all_of(input.cbegin() + input.length()/2, input.cend(),[](const char letter){return letter=='b';});
  if (is_correct) std::cout << "Pattern entered does match the language\n";
  else  std::cout << "Pattern entered does not match the language\n"; 
  return 0;
}
```

Notice that there is no need for any `stack`. Of course that's a matter of taste, some might prefer verbosity over size.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look through this program... :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Khalil Khalaf's idea:

```
bool isInLanguage(string w)
{
  stack <char> charStack;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++)
  {
    if (w[i] == 'a' && i > 0) // skip fisrt character if it is an a
      charStack.push(w[i]);
    else if (w[i] == 'b')
    {
      if (charStack.size() > 0)
        charStack.pop();
      else // is something like abababababa
        return false;
    }
  }

// Finally, the stack should be empty
return charStack.size() == 0;
}
```

Example of output on a quick test:
[image]